# How does microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll work?

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I want to download mail attachments from EXCHANGE into folder.
Thanks to help here I got code from http://gsexdev.blogspot.nl/2010/01/writing-simple-scripted-process-to.html.

I guess it works but my server does not have microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll folder. Please, can you explain me how it works all together? Is microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll this free? I found downloadable version here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42951.

But I really do not understand how it works together and what I need and what I dont need.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, it is definitely free. You download and install it and it'll put the dll somewhere. The code at that link is powershell (that's what you were after in your last question). Are you comfortable with powershell? Again there are many introductions to powershell online. You can learn everything online, you just need patience to learn and the right search terms! I notice that link also points back at here which has some of the more initial code: http://gsexdev.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/using-ews-managed-api-with-powershell.html

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I have never used PowerShell but I hope I can manage it somehow :D Please, how does DDL work with Exchange? Powershell is query language of Exchange and DDL is ..? Thank you :)

Comment: I don't know what you mean by DDL sorry. Do you mean DLL? Powershell is actually a windows scripting language for _anything_. Not just Exchange. When you get the  microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll file, powershell can use it to manipulate Exchange.